# How to connect a spring-boot app to mariadb in docker-compose?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

How can I let a `spring-boot` application communicate with a database container, without having to expose the db container port to the host system?

`docker-compose.yml`:
version: '3.7'

services:

```
  app:
    container_name: my_app
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mariadb://db:3306/dev
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: mariadb:10
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: rootpw
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dev
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    #ports:
    #  - 3306:3306
volumes:
  db:
```

I'm looking for a way that app + db can directly communicate with each other, but without having to open the port to the host.

Because, if I enable the `3306:3306` ports in `db` section, I get the message that the port (on my host) is already in use. Which makes sense, as I'm running a local `mariadb` additionally on the host.

So how could I share the port directly between those two containers, without exposing the port to the host system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was probably a caching or volume issue. After I cleaned everything in docker, the example above works. *No* need to expose a port explicit for spring to communicate with the `db:3306` container.